# Use CGI script as image provider with cache ability

Tags: perl, caching, cgi

I am trying to use a CGI script to act as static provider for my application assets. Since I am relatively new to Perl, I don't think my code is the best way to achieve what I want. If you have better code, let me know. Here's my recent script

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use lib "/usr/share/perl/5.10.1";
$asset_path = "/home/foo/public_html/assets/img/";
$uri_asset_path = "http://v2.foo.com/assets/img/";
use File::stat;
use Time::localtime;
$ENV{QUERY_STRING}=~ s/:/\//g;
$file = $asset_path . $ENV{QUERY_STRING};
unless (-e $file) {
print header('text/html','404 Not Found'); 
exit();
} 
$raw_last_modified = ctime(stat($file)->mtime);
$age = 30*24*60*60;
$date_day = substr $raw_last_modified, 0, 3;
$date_mon = substr $raw_last_modified, 4, 3;
$date_mon = substr $raw_last_modified, 4, 3;
$date_d = substr $raw_last_modified, 8, 2;
$date_time = substr $raw_last_modified, 11, 8;
$date_year = substr $raw_last_modified, 20, 4;
$last_modified = "$date_day, $date_d $date_mon $date_year $date_time GMT";
use CGI qw/:standard/;
use LWP::UserAgent;
my $ua = LWP::UserAgent->new;
my $response = $ua->get("$uri_asset_path/$ENV{QUERY_STRING}");
unless ($response->is_success){
    print header('text/html','404 Not Found'); 
    exit();
}
if(defined($ENV{'HTTP_IF_MODIFIED_SINCE'})){
    if ($ENV{'HTTP_IF_MODIFIED_SINCE'} == $last_modified){
        print header('text/html','304 Not Modified');
        return();
    } 
}
print header(-type=>'image/png',-expires=>'+30d',-last_modified => $last_modified,-cache_control => 'max-age='.$age.', must-revalidate');
print $response->content;
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It does not look like you have a specific question. I am assuming you are soliciting advice on how to write a CGI script properly.

I do not see why there is any need to write a CGI script for this. Just configure your web server properly to add `expires` and [Etag](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/core.html#fileetag) information.

You should add `use warnings;` and `use strict;` to your script, run it in 'taint' mode, not use `$ENV{QUERY_STRING}` directly, but access variables provided using `CGI.pm`'s `param` method etc.

I do not understand why `LWP::UserAgent` makes an appearance, why you are issuing a `GET`.

Perhaps you can explain why you are doing what you are doing and formulate a specific question in line with the Q&A nature of this site.

In addition, you might want to read [How (and how not) to Control Caches](http://www.mnot.net/cache_docs/#CONTROL).

Comment: First, thanks for your response. Iam interesting, related with your statement : " I do not see why there is any need to write a CGI script for this", since i was use PHP to do this task before i try to convert them into perl script. What was i think, if i use perl script, i am able to gain more performance instead using my php (i am planning to use FastCGI too). I am in the middle of tunning my v2 application, and would consider all options to maximize performance and every milisecond which can maximize my application performance is my goals.

Comment: @toopay: Maybe it's just me, but regardless of the language you use, ensuring caching of images is better handled in the web server configuration rather than in a CGI script.

Comment: I know. Also, i realize at some point, using a CDN is better option to maximize performance, but i'm not ready yet (in budget). And Sinan, my application is including some of static resource which can not (and should not) caching, like user picture, user custom css and other user stuff. So my REST service should provide an actual or newest resource, and in other hand other static resource can be cache properly. Since you're looks like a Perl Geek, did you really think using some perl script didnt do anything with my app performance?

Comment: For your question, why  i use GET, just to reference to static file. Shortly, in my css for example, for now i have something like these to referencing an image `http://v2.foo.com/cgi-bin/static.pl?icon:main:event.png` which actually grab an event.png from my asset path

Comment: @toopay I understand the words but I do not understand the problem. CDN aside, put the stuff you can't cached in one location, put the stuff you don't want cached in another, then configure the web server to send the appropriate headers.

Comment: @toopay But the `GET` in your script means your script creates opens an `INET` socket to the web server, reads the entire response, then sends it back to the client. First, that takes time. Second, it takes memory. Third, you did not even `binmode` `STDOUT`. I fail to see why this is better than configuring your web server.

Comment: Sorry for beeing unclear. Here some example. For manage asset file, like js for example, i have some class to collect all js file, read the content, minify them and put it into one cached file. What i do right now is, before compiling all of that js file, i will check file attribute and if some js file timestamp is newest than the cache file(eg: i pushed new js function to live site), that class is recompiling and recreated a cached file. There some task is have same behaviour/logic. Shortly, i use these way for better flexibility.

Comment: as i said i'm new to Perl and indeed i feel above code is lil bit far from what i expect, thats why i asked someone help :) Thanks for pointing some useful notes, will research for that. Originally i was interesting to convert my php class which serve static content into perl, because these archives : [link] http://www.fastcgi.com/archives/fastcgi-developers/2009-May/000245.html , and think that using Perl is more efficient rather than PHP, in this case.